# how to use String variable in SHOW method

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

i just started learning android and i'm stuck at this if anyone could help me

this is a part of the code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ListView listView;
SQLiteActivity db;
String [] x;

public void SHOW() {

    db.Read();
    String [] x = db.getAll();
    db.close();

}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    db = new SQLiteActivity(this);
    db.Write();
    db.deleteAll();
    db.insert("title1", "story1");
    db.insert("title2","story2");
    db.insert("title3", "story3");
    db.close();

    SHOW();

    String[] adapter = new String[] { "a", "b", "c",};

    ArrayAdapter<String> i = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, adapter);

    listView.setAdapter(i);
```

so the task is to define the x in method SHOW. and put the x in the ArrayAdapter

Comment: what do you mean by define the x in method SHOW? x as character or passing entire arra in SHOW method?

Comment: You probably need to define your question better

Comment: Again what do you mean by x? X as a String[] or X as 'x' to be added in existing ArrayAdapter?

Comment: String [] x; the x in String , yes want to be added in existing Arrayadapter : ArrayAdapter<String> i = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, adapter);

    listView.setAdapter(i);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want String[] to be passed and set as ArrayAdapter then probably following is the correct answer.

Change you SHOW method ::

```
public void SHOW(String [] input) {

    db.Read();
    String [] x = input;
    db.close();

}
```

Now use "x" as adapter in your code

```
ArrayAdapter<String> i = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, x);
```